# Can a GitLab CI job be bound to a user's ID?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

GitLab CI allows adding `rules` to jobs that will define when exactly the processing of a specific job will be triggered, e.g. only if a push to a specific branch takes place.

I would like to know if there is a way to also use the user's ID.

**REASON:** This comes from a concern regarding a license for a software that is needed for a project but the license is bound to a specific person (with the respective GitLab user account). If such a rule is added, only the user, who is a license holder, will be able to execute the job thus not getting into any conflict with the license agreement (which is very vague and sloppy as usual). The runner that executes the job and has access to the licensed software will also be restricted. If this setup is not possible, it will create a lot of extra work (downloading and sending the code, building it and then uploading it somewhere, so that it can be used).

Comment: There's a few distinctions to make... do you mean the commit author, the person who triggered the pipeline, or, in the case of manual jobs, the user who triggers the job? These can be different users in different circumstances. You can check the user ID before running a job in a few ways in GitLab, but whether that satisfies your software agreement is probably more of a legal problem (which requires the text of the agreement to reason about), not a GitLab or software problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) you can use in `rules:` to check the user:

- `GITLAB_USER_EMAIL` / `GITLAB_USER_ID` which refers to the user that triggered the pipeline (or in the case of manual jobs, the user that triggered the job)
- `CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR` refers to the email of the commit author in git. Keep in mind, unless you enforce GPG signing, users can push commits that use any arbitrary author.

For example, you may do something like:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $GITLAB_USER_ID == "123"
```

But keep in mind that GitLab CI `rules:` are not meant to be used as security measures and anyone who can change the CI YAML can simply remove those restrictions or create other jobs or modify source code in the repo that do the same script actions without the associated checks on user ID. `rules:` also only apply when the pipeline is *created* not necessarily when manual jobs are run. These variables can also be overridden.

---

Some other strategies you might use:

**Protected Environments**

If you have a GitLab Premium or Ultimate subscription, you might consider using the [protected environments feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/protected_environments.html) to select what users are allowed to trigger a "deploy" job for that environment.

**Runner configuration**

Since the software is installed on your runner, you could also consider using a script to check the user ID variables or an [ID token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/id_token_authentication.html) instead. For example you may [configure your runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) to have a `pre_build_script` or `pre_get_sources` configuration that performs this check.

---

Whether or not any of these things satisfy your legal obligations under the software licensing agreement is another story.